# Text View under Grid View

Tags: android, gridview, crash, textview

How can I add text view under images in Grid view?
I got this code but when I launch app it crashes.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    TextView text;
    private String[] mThumbTxt = {
            "Some text view 1", "Some text view 2", "Some text view 3", " Some text view 4"
    };


    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,  R.drawable.img4, 
        R.drawable.img5,  R.drawable.img6, 
        R.drawable.img7,  R.drawable.img20, 
        R.drawable.img8,  R.drawable.img21, 
        R.drawable.img9,  R.drawable.img22, 
        R.drawable.img10,  R.drawable.img23, 
        R.drawable.img11,  R.drawable.img24, 
        R.drawable.img12,  R.drawable.img25, 
        R.drawable.img13,  R.drawable.img26, 
        R.drawable.img14,  R.drawable.img27, 
        R.drawable.img15,  R.drawable.img28, 
        R.drawable.img16,  R.drawable.img29, 
        R.drawable.img17,  R.drawable.img30, 
        R.drawable.img18,  R.drawable.img31, 
        R.drawable.img19,  
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(270, 270));
    text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
    return imageView;
}


}
```

So what do I need to do? Create text view inside grid view? Or I can do it with string?
With this code I get error.

```
03-04 11:53:50.188: W/dalvikvm(12926): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41aac8b0)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at gsoft.relaxingringtones.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:64)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2181)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2196)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1290)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5508)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-04 11:53:50.208: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: should ask your questions separately: why you're getting the npe, and how to change your layout.  While changing your layout may magically make the npe disappear, the two aren't really related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma `","` from the last position in your `mThumbIds`

Change it

```
 public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
      ....................................
        R.drawable.img18,  R.drawable.img31, 
        R.drawable.img19,  <---- remove comma from here.
};
```

Write your array as below:

```
 public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
      ....................................
        R.drawable.img18,  R.drawable.img31, 
        R.drawable.img19  <---- removed comma from here.
};
```

Also you forget to initialize your `TextView` in your `getView` method that is why its throwing nullpointer exception for your `TextView`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
     text=new TextView(mContext);
  ..........................................
    text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

Always make sure the size of the `mThumbTxt` must be same as `mThumbIds` otherwise it will throw the error of IndexOutOfBounds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should initialize the textview in getView method before using

```
text = new TextView(this);
text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
```

After adding textview you have to return view of type linearlayout or RelativeLayout to display image and text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `findViewById` for your `TextView` or add a `TextView` dynamically ..

```
text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
```

the code doesn't know where to set that text, where your "`text`" is